# Cocoa: Get the Title of WebView

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I make a simple webview to user share with twitter and would like to know:

How can a get the title from a webview and put in on a string...

Answer (score 9):

Set your web view's `frameLoadDelegate` and implement the [`webView:didReceiveTitle:forFrame:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/WebKit/Protocols/WebFrameLoadDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/webView:didReceiveTitle:forFrame:) method:

```
- (void)webView:(WebView *)sender didReceiveTitle:(NSString *)title forFrame:(WebFrame *)frame
{
    if (frame == [myWebView mainFrame]) {
        NSLog(@"Title: %@", title);
        //...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
NSString *title = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.title"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `-(NSString *)mainFrameTitle` method. this method Return The HTML title of the loaded page. Returns @"" if the loaded document is not HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Set your WebView's resourceLoadDelegate. It will be called every time there is a request:

```
webView:resource:didReceiveResponse:fromDataSource:
```

the datasource has a pageTitle property. Use this.

This is preferable to polling for mainFrameTitle.